# Hello SMS - how can I directly jump to an existing conversation?

Tags: sms

I like Hello SMS, but there's something I'd like to be able to do, and seems reasonable, but I can't see how to do it.  Conversations are shown via icons representing individual people down the left hand side, and you can scroll and choose one to review a conversation.  However, sometimes the conversation I want to view took place a long time ago, or is otherwise hard to hunt out, and I want to jump straight to it.

If you send a new message to someone you are shown the conversion, including your new message (and that conversation jumps to the top of the list), but until you send you see nothing and obviously sometimes I want to look at a conversation without sending a message.

Is there a way of jumping to a specific existing conversation in Hello SMS, without sending a message?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Hello SMS for a long time and believe me, if there was an option for this I would have done it a long time ago.

The only way possible to send a text to make it jump to the top as you mentioned.